# How do I enable automatic tooltips for buttons on a toolbar?

Tags: windows, winapi, tooltip, toolbar

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760439.aspx), if I do not set the `BTNS_SHOWTEXT` style to a button, will not shown on the button text, but when the mouse hovers over the button, you will see tooltip with the text.

So I do not understand why this code sample text displayed on the button, and not shown a tooltip?

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HINSTANCE instance;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    instance = hInstance;

    WNDCLASSEX wcex; 

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style           = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; 
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc; 
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0; 
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;  
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));  
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1); 
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL; 
    wcex.lpszClassName  = L"Example"; 
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"Example", L"", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Initialize common controls.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC   = ICC_COOL_CLASSES | ICC_BAR_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    // create toolbar
    HWND hWndToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0 , TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS,
            0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU)0, instance, NULL);

    HIMAGELIST hImageList = ImageList_Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR16 | ILC_MASK, 3, 0);

    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)hImageList);
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);

    TBBUTTON tbb[1] = 
    {
        { 0, 0, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_BUTTON, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"New" },
    };

    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, (UINT) TB_ADDBUTTONS, 1, (LPARAM)&tbb);

    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
    ShowWindow(hWndToolbar , SW_SHOW);

    // show the main window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);  
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE: 
            return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is *almost* right, it's only missing a single line:

```
SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETMAXTEXTROWS, 0, 0);
```

You can put it somewhere between the creation of the toolbar window and where you display it. It's just more initialization code. For test purposes, I added it before sending the `TB_AUTOSIZE` message.

Now it works just as described: hover over the toolbar button and you see a tooltip containing the button text. Only one caveat: the button's text is not actually displayed in the button itself.

If you think about it, that kind of makes sense. Basically, there's no point in showing the text in a tooltip if the entire string is already visible on the button itself. The only way that the automatic tooltip is going to be shown is if the button's text doesn't fit. Sending the [`TB_SETMAXTEXTROWS` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787443.aspx) ensures that the text will never fit by setting the maximum number of rows available for text to 0.

This is covered in more detail in an MSDN how-to article: [How to Display Tooltips for Buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298386.aspx).

Comment: Your answer did solve the problem, but in a roundabout way, the other answer works by the rules. Thank you anyway !

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but I don't understand what "rules" you think I'm breaking here. The linked documentation says the same thing.

Comment: I mean in MSDN Write, *to display Tooltips for Buttons, The button style must be used with the `TBSTYLE_LIST` style and the `TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS` extended style.* and this really solves the problem alone. and is not mentioned on MSDN should also call `TB_SETMAXTEXTROWS` message to display tooltips.

Comment: @user: I don't know what you mean when you say that my answer is not mentioned on MSDN. [The page I linked to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298386.aspx) says: *"Set the tooltip text as the iString member of the TBBUTTON structure for each button. You must also send a TB_SETMAXTEXTROWS message and set the maximum text rows to 0, so that the text does not appear as the button label rather than as a tooltip."*

Comment: Of course, that same page gives multiple options. My answer discusses the first one, Hans's answer discusses the second one. The third and fourth ways do not display tooltips automatically, they force you to write code that displays them. All of them work, you're free to pick any of them.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the MSDN article you linked:

> Version 5.81. Specifies that button text should be displayed. All buttons can have text, but only those buttons with the BTNS_SHOWTEXT button style will display it. This button style must be used with the TBSTYLE_LIST style and the TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS extended style.

There are **three** requirements listed here.  Let's tackle them one by one.

- Version 5.81

That's a version of common controls that requires a manifest in your executable.  If it is missing then you'll get the legacy version, v4.70 from c:\windows\system32.  Which doesn't know anything about BTNS_SHOWTEXT.  The easiest way to specify the manifest entry is by inserting the /MANIFESTDEPENDENCY linker option with a #pragma in your code.  Make it look similar to this:

```
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

With the last line added.  That should be immediately visible if you didn't yet do this, the highlight for the button now shows a gradient.  Other parts of your window will similarly have acquired the visual styles theme.

- must be used with the TBSTYLE_LIST style

That requires changing your CreateWindowEx call, include that style bit:

```
// create toolbar
HWND hWndToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0 , TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL,
     WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS | TBSTYLE_LIST,
     0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU)0, instance, NULL);
```

- and the TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS extended style

That requires using the TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE message to turn that extended style bit on:

```
SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, 0, (LPARAM)TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS);
ShowWindow(hWndToolbar , SW_SHOW);
```

With the second line added.  You'll now see the tooltip as expected when you hover over the toolbar button.  You will still need to do something to make the button actually visible to the user, right now it doesn't have a distinguishing feature.  A bitmap is the usual approach.

Comment: Why can not I set the extended style `TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS` in creating of window, as first parameter in `CreateWindowEx()` function, and I need to determine it just through `SendMessage()`?

Comment: Because these extended styles are turned on with a message, not a style flag.  Thus the TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE message.