# How to hide text on toolbar buttons (TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS with TBSTYLE_LIST doesn't hide text)

Tags: c, winapi, toolbar

I followed [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298381.aspx) to create a simple toolbar.

I want only some buttons to have text beside them, but not all. According to the MSDN docs [over here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760430.aspx), I'd have to use `TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS` with `TBSTYLE_LIST`. So I changed the `CreateWindowEx` call in the above example to this:

```
CreateWindowEx(TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL,
               WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_LIST, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               hWndParent, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

Everything else remains the same. Even though I still only use `BTNS_AUTOSIZE` for my button styles (no `BTNS_SHOWTEXT`), it shows the button text next to each button. What am I missing?

I also read [this article about list-style buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775452.aspx#list). Unfortunately, the procedure isn't explained much; it just states the `TBSTYLE_LIST` moves the text to the right, while for some buttons (stop, refresh) the text just magically disappears entirely. That doesn't seem to happen for me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16771151/1850797), you need to

a) make sure that you are linking to Common Controls v5.81 (or higher)

b) call `CreateWindowEx()` with the first parameter (extended style) as zero

c) call

```
SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, 0, (LPARAM)TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS);
ShowWindow(hWndToolbar , SW_SHOW);
```

The reason for turning on the extended style later on is that `these extended styles are turned on with a message, not a style flag. Thus the TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE message`.

Answer (score 1):

The extended toolbar styles need to be set with the [`TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, they can't be passed to `CreateWindowEx()`.

Comment: Yeah... and here I thought `dwExStyle` in `CreateWindowEx` kind of sounds like it can be used for extended styles. This answer works, but the other guy was a minute faster and has less reputation.

Comment: He was a minute slower actually, but lets not quibble :)

Comment: Nuts! I take that back. I checked the code in my class library again, and it only works for `TB_SETSTYLE`, not the extended styles. Sorry about that! :-)